# Как вывести сплошной текст построчно?

Tags: php

Текст представляет собой большой список, как на скриншоте ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать вывод подобным образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какая функция может подобное?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_encode` имеет флаг `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` для форматированного вывода JSON.

```
$data = [['id' => ....];
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

либо если выводите уже имеющийся json, то декодируйте и кодируйте заново.

*зы: очевидно, сие действо имеет смысл только для удобства просмотра и отладки, в рабочем окружении сие не используется*